# using jquery auto complete pugin with rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

In my rails application i am trying to use the auto complete plugin.Its not working.Please help me out  here.

View file:

```
%td.grid.full_panels
    -table_panel "Assign Testers" do
      %table
        %th Name
        -puts "testers=#{@testers}"
        = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers" 
        = form.text_field :tester_tokens,:class=>"users_auto_complete" 
        - @testers.each do |tester|
          %tr
            %td=tester.name
            %td=check_box_tag "release[tester_ids][]", tester.id,   @release.is_tester_assigned(tester)
      =will_paginate @testers
@testers=['sramya','scharron','jstinson']
:javascript  
data=#{@tmp_testers.to_json}
= javascript_include_tag "pages/ic", :cache => true
```

Controller file:

```
def new
@release = Release.new
@ic_ids = params[:ic_ids] ? params[:ic_ids] : []
 @testers = User.find_by_sql("select * from users where id in(select user_id from user_role_assignments where role_id in (select id from roles where name like 'Tester')) order by name").paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>30)   
 if params[:project_id]
  @release.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
end
end
```

Javascript:

```
$('.users_auto_complete').live("keypress",function() {
var data= #{@tmp_testers.to_json}
alert (data);
$("#release_tester_tokens").autocomplete(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your jquery is in `(document).ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.users_auto_complete').live("keypress",function() {
var data= #{@tmp_testers.to_json}
alert (data);
$("#release_tester_tokens").autocomplete(data);
});

});
```

Comment: Hi Kanishka,thanks for answering me,I have the jquery in a separate function and I have added it in the text box. form.text_field :tester_tokens,:class=>"users_auto_complete"